# Different name google map in my website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am integrating google maps v3 javascript api in a website for an Arab company.

every thing is working well except for the "Arab Gulf" is appearing as "Persian Gulf" in the website but it shows as "Arab Gulf" in maps.google and its driving them crazy

why is it appearing diferent in my website?
and is there a way to change that ?

Comment: How are you loading the API and map? Have you tried [Localization](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization)?

Comment: that did it, thank you. you can add a reply so i can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Localization](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization) in the Google Maps Javascript API.

**Localization**

You may localize your Maps API application both by altering default language settings and by setting the application's region code, which alters how it behaves based on a given country or territory.

Answer (score -1):

Add parameter region=EG to your script src,
or use this script

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&language=ar&region=EG"></script>
```

It works fine.